# RecyclerView crashing app (due to new design library?)

Tags: android, parent-child, material-design, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to populate my RecyclerView with a list and my app is crashing with the error of "this child already have a parent".
Now I think it might be related to the new android studio and the new design library.

**I did try both false and true argument while calling the inflate method on the RecyclerView Adapter**

here is my code:

---

Activity:

```
RecyclerView usersRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.users_recyclerView);
usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(appUsers);
usersRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
usersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
usersRecyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
```

---

activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.sarigbrand.japanesequickcourse.ChatActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_chat" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

content_chat.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.sarigbrand.japanesequickcourse.ChatActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_chat"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heb_loading"
        android:id="@+id/loading_textView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorRed500"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/users_recyclerView">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

UsersAdapter:

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserHolder> {

    ArrayList<AppUser> appUsers;

    public UsersAdapter (ArrayList<AppUser> appUsers){
        this.appUsers = appUsers;
    }

    public static class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView userNameTV;
        public UserHolder(TextView tv) {
            super(tv);
            userNameTV = tv;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UsersAdapter.UserHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_user_list_view, parent, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name_textView);
        UserHolder userHolder = new UserHolder(tv);
        return userHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserHolder holder, int position) {
        AppUser user = appUsers.get(position);
        holder.userNameTV.setText(user.userName);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appUsers.size();
    }
}
```

---

error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sarigbrand.japanesequickcourse, PID: 8642
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4309)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:585)
at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:6254)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6212)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6200)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.vie
```

Comment: Never use `LayoutInflater.from()` for things tied to an activity. Call `getLayoutInflater()` on the hosting `Activity` and use that.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare I got the answer, it wasn't the layout inflater but i would like to hear more about the inflater issue, isn't all the views bound to an activity?

Comment: also I didn't understand how to get the layout inflater on the hosting activity

Answer (score 1):

You're inflating a view, but then only storing one of its child views in your holder:

```
@Override
public UsersAdapter.UserHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_user_list_view, parent, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name_textView);
    // Make a holder that takes v in the constructor.
    UserHolder userHolder = new UserHolder(tv);
    return userHolder;
}
```

A [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) should be instantiated with the ROOT view that represents the entire item to display.  In your case, that should be "v".  This is what gets added and removed to the RecyclerView as it scrolls.  You then pick out other views within it and store those as members for fast and easy access.

Comment: Thank a lot! I passed LinearLayout to the super and added TextView as a variable and it worked

Comment: If you could accept this answer as the correct one, I would appreciate it (not just upvote).

Answer (score 0):

As Doug stevenson explained I inflated a view but passed only the text view.
here is the code after the changes

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserHolder> {

    ArrayList<AppUser> appUsers;

    public UsersAdapter (ArrayList<AppUser> appUsers){
        this.appUsers = appUsers;
    }

    public static class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public TextView textView;
        public UserHolder(LinearLayout layout, TextView tv) {
            super(layout);
            linearLayout = layout;
            textView = tv;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UsersAdapter.UserHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_user_list_view, parent, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.user_name_textView);
        UserHolder userHolder = new UserHolder(layout, tv);
        return userHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserHolder holder, int position) {
        AppUser user = appUsers.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(user.userName);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appUsers.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually, the ViewHolder subclass will figure out which views go to which members based on the root view it was passed. There's no reason to need to do that in onCreateViewHolder().  After all, that is the responsibility of the ViewHolder.  (see javadoc at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html)